# Join voice channel (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

When I try to let my bot join my voice channel, I get this error:

`await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)` (line that generates the error)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
 ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
 File "bot.py", line 215, in sfx
vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 3176, in join_voice_channel
session_id_future = self.ws.wait_for('VOICE_STATE_UPDATE', session_id_found)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'wait_for'
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 848, in process_commands
yield from command.invoke(ctx)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 369, in invoke
yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'wait_for'
```

I'm getting this error with channel name and channel ID

Function:

```
description = "Bot"
bot_prefix = "!"

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(description=description, command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
   author = ctx.message.author
   voice_channel = author.voice_channel
   vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
```

Comment: `self.ws` is `None`. No idea how to fix it, you haven't given a repeatable example.

Comment: I posted the function

Comment: Can we see more of your code?

Comment: Posted everything. (except the `onready()` event). I tried to load the opus files but it didn't change anything @GiantsLoveDeathMetal

Answer (score 1):

This is the code i use to make it work.

```
#Bot.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="|")

async def on_ready():
    print ("Ready")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    channel = author.voice_channel
    await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.

Comment: @pirho I know it would be a lot better to explain it, but unfortunately I just started with python myself and barely understand it. I tough it would be better to at least leave the code that worked for me since he posted this 1 month ago without any responses.

Comment: for me, there is no function called `join_voice_channel` for my bot, and it throws an error. Is this only me?

Comment: @cs1349459 I was having the same problem, think this may have been an old way to do it, but using `await channel.connect()` worked for me. I had to install PyNaCl using `pip install PyNaCl` then just add `import nacl` to the file

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the

> from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient
>   line and it shoudl be ok.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

Comment: could you elaborate to help us understand this code?