# Python - How do I make a join command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to create a ".join" command for my bot but everything I've tried didn't work & I tried a ton of things

Here's something I've tried, I tried it in a few other ways too:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
 channel=ctx.message.author.voice.VoiceChannel

 await client.join_VoiceChannel(channel)
```

It gives this error:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'VoiceChannel'`

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47639139/10626861) work for you? I believe you are calling author.voice.VoiceChannel and should be just calling author.VoiceChannel

Comment: I'm now getting this error ```discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'``` and with ```author.VoiceChannel``` its the same

Answer (score 1):

```
join_voice_channel
```

works for older versions of discord.py

This code block should work:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    message = ctx.message
    channel_id = ctx.message.author.voice.channel.id
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `join_voice_channel` to make the bot join a voice channel as it says in the [Async docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.12/api.html#discord.Client.join_voice_channel)
Try this:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    author=ctx.message.author
    await bot.join_voice_channel(author.voice_channel)
```

Comment: `Bot has no attribute join_voice_channel` is the error im getting

Comment: Are you sure you're using Async? You probably have rewrite installed. In python put in `import discord;print(discord.__version__)` to check the version or discord.py you have, if async then idk whats wrong with the script if rewrite then your script is wrong, If the version given is 1.0.0 or above then you're using Rewrite, but if it's less than 1.0.0 then it's Async (Also I'd recommend you use Rewrite)

Comment: I am using rewrite, I like to stay up-to-date